# .htaccess query string being ignored

Tags: .htaccess

I've got these 2 query strings in my .htaccess file that check if the query string contains `name_const` or `CHART` but the rewrite rule redirect only gets triggered when query strings contains `name_const` and not when it contains `CHART`. 
What am I doing wrong here? Can I not do this same line twice or something?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)name_const($|&) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)CHAR($|&) [NC]
```

and the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule .* page [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*name_const.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*CHART.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /page [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Use the `[OR]` flag to match either `name_const` or `chart` in the query string.

Comment: Yup, that's it. Thanks